# What do I write down as Domain in Powershell Start-Process credentials when im in a workgroup?

Tags: powershell, windows-11, workgroup

I am trying to roll out a script on a location to change an office activation remotely.
I thought I knew hout to do this but I've been stuck on something weird. it always gives me this error

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: De gebruikersnaam of het wachtwo
ord is onjuist.
At line:2 char:1
+ Start-Process "\\10.0.0.1\scripts\WordActivationAdmin.ps1" -Credentia ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartP
   rocessCommand
```

The code I run is:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Force

$hostname = get-content env:computername
    
$username = "$hostname\localUserAdmin"
$password = "Password"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword


Start-Process "\\10.0.0.1\scripts\WordActivationAdmin.ps1" -Credential $credential
```

I am 100% sure the password and username are both right. so I think im entering the username in the wrong way or something like that.

Comment: The error message in English means "username or password is incorrect". Your Credential  parameter seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want the hostname of your local machine, but instead the hostname of the remote system.

Try with

```
$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('10.0.0.1').HostName
```

<sup>Sometimes the hostname has a suffix you need to remove like `.home`. In that case use

`$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('10.0.0.1').HostName.Split(".")[0]`</sup>

BTW. To run something on a remote system, you want `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $credential -Scriptblock { ... }`